# How to check if everything needed is installed for Open street map server?

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap, boundary, mapnik

I am configuring Open Street Maps by following these steps: http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

I am using the same packages, but for Debian, and the defaults give me the slippymap site example. The map loads from Mapnik option, but not from the Local option. Everything seems to be configured, except that I didn't added the boundaries and processed coastline data. The information I found about that seems ambiguous to me. Also I can't find rendered tiles in the mod_tile folder.

Any ideas how to check if Mapnik is installed and configured correctly and how to import the boundaries and coastlines data into Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot for this issue, however this didn't help. Even Debian and Ubuntu are similar as package management the packages for Ubuntu didn't work on Debian. In that case a better approach is to use Ubuntu with Ubuntu packages for OSM or build from source if there is no choice to switch from Debian. Hope this helps someone.